# Finding location using Huawei E156G

Tags: c#, vb.net, api, telecommunication

I have a Huawei E156G 3G dongle and i want to use it to find my current location using VB or C#  like it happened in google maps for mobile. Can i use AT Commands to achieve this or is this possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to ask the 3G dongle for cell tower information and lookup the cell tower information in a database containing cell tower/location information.

Or you could also use a traceroute to see which routers(ip-addresses) you'll find on the way and retrieve information from a database containing IP address/location information.

Both solutions take a lot of programming and I don't know a default way to do this. There might be some library to do all this.